# Error Parsing .dae (Collada) file... cannot find issue

Tags: parsing, import, export, collada

For the past couple of weeks I've been working on creating a custom Collada exporter for Revit Architecture, based on the example give [here](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/07/graphics-pipeline-custom-exporter.html).  In order to ensure that my output is correct, I'm comparing it to the output generated by the [Revit to Lumion Bridge](http://lumion3d.com/revit-to-lumion-bridge/).  I've gone though the files a half-dozen times or more and, aside from the way I name my elements, I cannot find any ways in which my export differs from theirs.  For some reason, however, theirs imports just fine and mine doesn't.  I'm building this for use with Unity, but I've also tried it with 3ds max and Blender, with the same results in each program.

I was hoping someone could point me in the direction of a Collada debug tool, or that someone may be able to look through the two files and see if they can find something I've missed.

Custom Exporter Output: [Custom Exporter.dae](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qwh61e7yk7btuee/Custom%20Exporter.dae)

Revit to Lumion Bridge Output: [Revit to Lumion Bridge.dae](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sn0xgnja5i41l1e/Revit%20to%20Lumion%20Bridge.dae)

Thanks in advance for any help, this is really giving me a headache >_>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try is [schema validation](https://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/Schema_validation). If you run xmllint on your file, it might discover the problem. This only finds errors that violate the schema though, so it won't catch *all* problems.

Comment: I wasn't able to get that specific program to work, but knowing what to do lead me to an online validator, which was able to tell me that I had a problem in my naming system... for some reason my strings are adding quotation marks where none are called for... very odd, I'll have to figure that out.  Thank you so much for the help!

Validator: http://www.corefiling.com/opensource/schemaValidate.html

Comment: Yeah, I looked at it some more, it turns out that my family names in Revit included quotation marks to denote inches, which is what was causing the problem.  All it took was a simple string.Replace....  Again, thank you for the help.